# I have error secure apache on Digital Ocean?

Tags: ubuntu, ssl-certificate, digital-ocean

I want to set https for my hosting on ubuntu 18 under Digital Ocean as it is written here:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-apache-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-18-04

But I had problems with ufw settuings:

```
# sudo ufw status
Status: inactive
root@nsn-do-lamp:/etc/apache2/sites-available# sudo ufw allow 'Apache'
Rules updated
Rules updated (v6)
root@nsn-do-lamp:/etc/apache2/sites-available# sudo ufw status
Status: inactive
root@nsn-do-lamp:/etc/apache2/sites-available# sudo systemctl reload apache2
root@nsn-do-lamp:/etc/apache2/sites-available# sudo ufw status
Status: inactive
root@nsn-do-lamp:/etc/apache2/sites-available# sudo ufw allow 'Apache Full'
Skipping adding existing rule
Skipping adding existing rule (v6)
root@nsn-do-lamp:/etc/apache2/sites-available# sudo ufw delete allow 'Apache'
Rules updated
Rules updated (v6)
root@nsn-do-lamp:/etc/apache2/sites-available# sudo ufw status
Status: inactive
```

I see that status is inactive.

I tried to make :

## sudo ufw app list

```
Available applications:
  Apache
  Apache Full
  Apache Secure
  OpenSSH
root@nsn-do-lamp:/etc/apache2/sites-available# sudo ufw allow 'Apache'
Rules updated
Rules updated (v6)
root@nsn-do-lamp:/etc/apache2/sites-available# sudo ufw status
Status: inactive
```

I think this error is critical and did not proceed with next commands. Why error and how to fix it ?

**MODIFIED BLOCK # 2:**
I did :

```
# ufw allow 80
Rules updated
Rules updated (v6)
root@nsn-do-lamp:~# sudo ufw app list
Available applications:
  Apache
  Apache Full
  Apache Secure
  OpenSSH
root@nsn-do-lamp:~# sudo ufw status
Status: inactive
root@nsn-do-lamp:~# sudo service apache2 restart
root@nsn-do-lamp:~# sudo ufw status
Status: inactive
```

Also I restarted the OS, but status is inactive anyway. What is wrong?
The same using ports 443.
I check my ports :

```
# netstat -a  
Active Internet connections (servers and established) 
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       
tcp        0      0 localhost:domain        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:ssh             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 localhost.lo:postgresql 0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 localhost.localdo:mysql 0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      
tcp        0    316 box.example.com:ssh     213.109.234.130:44188   ESTABLISHED 
tcp6       0      0 [::]:ssh                [::]:*                  LISTEN      
tcp6       0      0 [::]:http               [::]:*                  LISTEN      
udp     7680      0 localhost:domain        0.0.0.0:*                           
udp     2560      0 localhost.localdo:55370 localhost.localdo:55370 ESTABLISHED 
raw6       0      0 [::]:ipv6-icmp          [::]:*                  7           
Active UNIX domain sockets (servers and established) 
Proto RefCnt Flags       Type       State         I-Node   Path 
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    133990   /run/user/0/systemd/notify 
unix  2      [ ACC ]     SEQPACKET  LISTENING     11724    /run/udev/control 
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     133993   /run/user/0/systemd/private 
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     133997   /run/user/0/gnupg/S.gpg-agent.extra 
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     133998   /run/user/0/gnupg/S.gpg-agent.ssh 
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     133999   /run/user/0/gnupg/S.dirmngr 
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     134000   /run/user/0/gnupg/S.gpg-agent.browser 
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     134001   /run/user/0/gnupg/S.gpg-agent 
unix  3      [ ]         DGRAM                    11678    /run/systemd/notify 
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     11681    /run/systemd/private 
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     11686    /run/systemd/journal/stdout 
unix  9      [ ]         DGRAM                    11688    /run/systemd/journal/socket 
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     11722    /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket 
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     11762    /run/lvm/lvmpolld.socket 
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     18480    /var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432 
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    11995    /run/systemd/journal/syslog 
unix  6      [ ]         DGRAM                    12052    /run/systemd/journal/dev-log 
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     18571    /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock 
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     15792    /var/lib/lxd/unix.socket 
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     15805    @ISCSIADM_ABSTRACT_NAMESPACE 
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     15797    /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket 
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     15764    /run/snapd.socket 
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     15766    /run/snapd-snap.socket 
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     15785    /run/acpid.socket 
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     15817    /run/uuidd/request 
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    12404     
unix  3      [ ]         DGRAM                    14820     
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    12660     
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     16768     
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     15931    /run/systemd/journal/stdout 
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     15800     
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     18050    /run/systemd/journal/stdout 
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    14810     
unix  3      [ ]         DGRAM                    14526     
unix  3      [ ]         DGRAM                    14528     
unix  3      [ ]         DGRAM                    133991    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     16814    /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket 
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     16811    /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket 
unix  3      [ ]         DGRAM                    14819     
unix  3      [ ]         DGRAM                    14527     
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    133966    
unix  3      [ ]         DGRAM                    12886     
unix  3      [ ]         DGRAM                    12885     
unix  3      [ ]         DGRAM                    14817     
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    14522     
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     16812    /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket 
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    16802     
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     17880     
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     16809     
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     18049     
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     16810     
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     15799     
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     16815    /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket 
unix  3      [ ]         DGRAM                    133992    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     14392     
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     17140    /run/systemd/journal/stdout 
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    15083     
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     14393    /run/systemd/journal/stdout 
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     133964   /run/systemd/journal/stdout 
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     17881    /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket 
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     16775     
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     17138     
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     133945    
unix  3      [ ]         DGRAM                    14525     
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    17907     
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    133853    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     15929     
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     18536    /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket 
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     16247    /run/systemd/journal/stdout 
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     16246     
unix  3      [ ]         DGRAM                    11680     
unix  3      [ ]         DGRAM                    11679     
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     16168     
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     16169    /run/systemd/journal/stdout 
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     16406    /run/systemd/journal/stdout 
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     16813    /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket 
unix  3      [ ]         DGRAM                    14314     
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     18535     
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     16404     
unix  3      [ ]         DGRAM                    14818     
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     15007    /run/systemd/journal/stdout 
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     16728     
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    12850     
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    133953    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     17455     
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     15005     
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     14720    /run/systemd/journal/stdout 
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     12658     
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     13014    /run/systemd/journal/stdout 
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     17460    /run/systemd/journal/stdout 
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     12543     
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     16727     
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     13016    /run/systemd/journal/stdout 
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    16769     
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     16731    /run/systemd/journal/stdout 
unix  3      [ ]         DGRAM                    14315     
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     14718     
root@nsn-do-lamp:~# netstat --listening 
Active Internet connections (only servers) 
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       
tcp        0      0 localhost:domain        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:ssh             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 localhost.lo:postgresql 0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 localhost.localdo:mysql 0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      
tcp6       0      0 [::]:ssh                [::]:*                  LISTEN      
tcp6       0      0 [::]:http               [::]:*                  LISTEN      
udp     8448      0 localhost:domain        0.0.0.0:*                           
raw6       0      0 [::]:ipv6-icmp          [::]:*                  7           
Active UNIX domain sockets (only servers) 
Proto RefCnt Flags       Type       State         I-Node   Path 
unix  2      [ ACC ]     SEQPACKET  LISTENING     11724    /run/udev/control 
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     133993   /run/user/0/systemd/private 
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     133997   /run/user/0/gnupg/S.gpg-agent.extra 
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     133998   /run/user/0/gnupg/S.gpg-agent.ssh 
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     133999   /run/user/0/gnupg/S.dirmngr 
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     134000   /run/user/0/gnupg/S.gpg-agent.browser 
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     134001   /run/user/0/gnupg/S.gpg-agent 
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     11681    /run/systemd/private 
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     11686    /run/systemd/journal/stdout 
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     11722    /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket 
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     11762    /run/lvm/lvmpolld.socket 
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     18480    /var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432 
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     18571    /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock 
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     15792    /var/lib/lxd/unix.socket 
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     15805    @ISCSIADM_ABSTRACT_NAMESPACE 
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     15797    /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket 
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     15764    /run/snapd.socket 
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     15766    /run/snapd-snap.socket 
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     15785    /run/acpid.socket 
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     15817    /run/uuidd/request
```

Thanks!

Comment: Try `sudo ufw status numbered` to see what you already have. FWIW I don't do protocols with UFW or application names/profiles, I specify ports - `ufw allow 443` or `ufw allow 80`

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. 
Please look at MODIFIED BLOCK # 2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to to enable ufw with command

```
  sudo ufw enable
```

Comment: "Command may disrupt existing ssh connections. Proceed with operation (y|n)?" I used "y" and I could never again connect to the server with SSH, not from PuTTY nor from the DigitalOcean console. I had to destroy the Droplet. Whoever wants to use this option, be careful!

Comment: See https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-setup-a-firewall-with-ufw-on-an-ubuntu-and-debian-cloud-server: "If you’re connecting via SSH, make sure to set your SSH port, commonly port 22, to allow connections to be received. Otherwise, you could lock yourself out of your server."

Comment: Run `sudo ufw allow 22` before running `sudo ufw enable`, as explained at https://www.linode.com/community/questions/17360/ssh-and-sftp-stop-working-after-ufw-enable.